# C - Add char to beginnig of string

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

I try to create an array of string where each element is the concatenation of a char and a string.

For example:

> char base_array[4] = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};
>
> char *kmer = "ACGT";
>
> char *edge[4] = {"AACGT", "CACGT", "GACGT", "TACGT"};

I try with this code but generate segmentation fault.

```
char** kmer_head_append(const char *kmer, const char *base) {

    int i;
    char **edge = malloc(BASE * sizeof(char *));

    for ( i = 0; i < BASE; i++ ) {
        edge[i] = (char *) malloc((strlen(kmer) + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        strcpy(edge[i], &base[i]);
        *((*(edge + i)) + strlen(&base[i])) = kmer;
        *((*(edge + i)) + strlen(&base[i]) + 1) = '\0';
    }

    return edge;
}

int main(void) {
    
    char base_array[4] = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};
    char **edge = kmer_head_append("ACGT", base_array);
    return 0;
}
```

## EDIT:

If `char *kmer = "DEFG"` the output is an array where the element are `ADEFG`, `CDEFG`, `GDEFG` e `TDEFG`

Comment: Would you please revise the names used in the examples so that they correspond to each other in the way you intend?  Or at least present a sample call to your function?  It's hard to track the correspondances to figure out what you intend to be doing.

Comment: Note also that to "append" is to add something *at the end*.  What you seem to want to do is *pre*pend.

Comment: Not very clear, please change your example and show us the expected result for `char *kmer = "WXYZ"`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I just edit with your example

Comment: Perhaps you should create a function like `char *concatenate_char_str(char prefix, const char *str) { char *ret=malloc(1+strlen(str)+1); ret[0]=prefix; strcpy(ret+1, str); return ret; }` and use that in your function. Divide your problem into small enough chunks so it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need size of `char` not `char **`

```
edge[i] =  malloc((strlen(kmer) + 2)); //2 to hold char + \0
```

Don't use `strcpy` if you want to copy single `char`.

```
    strcpy(edge[i], &base[i]); --> edge[i][0] = base[i];
```

You are doing pointer assignment what you need is `strcpy`

```
*((*(edge + i)) + strlen(&base[i])) = kmer; --> strcpy((char *)&edge[i][1], kmer);
```

Remove below line as `\0` is already appended by `strcpy`.

```
    *((*(edge + i)) + strlen(&base[i]) + 1) = '\0';
```

---

Or simply

```
   sprintf(edge[i], "%c%s", base[i], kmer);
```

Comment: `strlen` doesn't work with non NUL terminated strings like `base_array`

Comment: The `sprintf` alternative is ever so much clearer and simpler.  The same can be done more manually, but I don't see why anyone would want that.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Thank you! I have only one question, I don't understand why it generate all error with `valgrind`. When I call the function, in the cycle for I destroy `free(*(edge + i))` and after the for `free(edge)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use valgrind to see your where you segfault.

```
 char **edge = kmer_head_append("ACGT", base_array); //base_array is a char str[4]
```

So in your prototype you need to have:

```
char** kmer_head_append(const char *kmer,  char base[4])
```

You can malloc base like that:

```
char **edge = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (4 + 1)); because base is equal to 4 and + 1 for putting NULL at the end
```

Then:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 4 + 1; i++ ) {
        edge[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (5 + 1)) ; // 5 for the new string and + 1 for '\0'
```

Do step by step !

Then yo just have to do your line with strcpy